# Squish: Enum as function parameter

Tags: python, c++, qt, enums, squish

Do someone know a workaround for use a enum as a function parameter in a c++ function and call them function with squish? 
The Enum was declared in a other class and namespace as the function itself. 
Following code is in use and works in qt:

Enum-class:

```
namespace prem {
     namespace space {

         class Controller : public QObject {
             Q_OBJECT
             Q_ENUMS(ID)

         public:

            enum ID { ONE, TWO, THREE };
          //.... other Stuff

         };
     } 
}
```

Using class:

```
namespace prem {
    namespace area {

        class Handler: public QObject {

        //...... some stuff

        public slot:

             void slotHandelID(prem::space::Controller::ID id) {
             // do some stuff 
             } 

        };
    }
}
```

Now I want to call in the python test script the slotHandelID Function.

```
controller = findObject("m_controller")
handler = findObject("m_handler")
handler.slotHandelID(controller.ONE)
```

But I get this

```
SyntaxError: No matching 'slotHandelID(int)' overload found: Following overloads are available:
    prem::area::Handler::slotHandelID(undefined)
```

When I define the `slotHandelID(prem::space::Controller::ID id)` in the `Controller` class the code works fine.

Comment: How do you call `slotHandelID`?

Comment: I think you are missing a ; following the enum definition.

Comment: I am not sure of the meaning of `public slot:` instead of `public:` too. Ok that is a QT specific extension.

Comment: the missing ; was a typo, and the code works fine. It's only a squish "problem". Yes ´public slot:´ is a qt extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is fixed during the new squish version 6.0.